# Error when building PHP with ZTS enabled

Tags: apache2, dpkg, php

I am trying to build a version of PHP 5 with ZTS support enabled to be able to use the PHP pthreads module.  I am trying to build from the sources in the package repo i.e. fetched build dependencies and source using

```
sudo apt-get build-dep php5
apt-get source php5
```

I tested building a `.deb` with the untouched sources with `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b` and that works fine.

Next I bumped the version number using `dch -i` and added `--enable-maintainer-zts` under the `COMMON_CONFIG` in the `debian/rules` file.

When I try running the `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b` command again I get the following error:

```
make[1]: *** [ext/date/php_date.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jonas/php/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build'
make: *** [build-apache2-stamp] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

Any clue what is failing/missing?

Comment: I am running the latest LTS of Ubuntu Server